# How can I fully simplify sum that includes absolute value?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion

Consider the following sum:

```
Sum[(n*(2 + (10^n - x + Abs[10^n - x])^2 - Abs[-2 + (10^n - x +
 Abs[10^n - x])^2])*(2 + (1 - 10^(-1 + n) + x + Abs[1 - 10^(-1 + n) +
 x])^2 - Abs[-2 + (1 - 10^(-1 + n) + x + Abs[1 - 10^(-1 + n) +
 x])^2]))/16, {n, 1, x}]
```

I want to fully simplify it and get rid of `Sum` like in this example:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(a+kd) = \frac{n}{2}(2a + (n-1) d)$$

I tried `Expand[]`, `Simplify[]`, `FullSimplify[]`, but it does not give the result I want.

What can I do?